# write or write binary for saving data to file in python?

Tags: python, file, machine-learning, keras

i am trying to save features from the directory to the file. The data and the error has been displayed below. What should be the correct "letter" in the **open** statement for saving the data without distorting it?

**Error**

```
write() argument must be str, not numpy.ndarray
```

**CODE**

```
generator1 = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255).flow_from_directory(train_data_dir,target_size=(img_width, img_height),batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=False)
    print("generator1 images loaded")

    for i in range(len(generator1)):
        kl = generator1[i]
        bottleneck_features_train = model.predict_on_batch(kl[0])
        print("first prediction")
        print (bottleneck_features_train)
        file =open('/home/rehan/predictions/bottleneck_features_train_%s.py'%i, 'w')
        file.write(bottleneck_features_train)
        file.close()
```

**Data**

```
 [[[ 0.50452518  0.          0.         ...,  0.          0.84091663  0.        ]
       [ 0.538715    0.          0.07498804 ...,  0.          0.50906491  0.        ]
       [ 0.5355916   0.          1.27406454 ...,  0.14854321  0.55418521  0.        ]
       [ 1.24407315  0.          1.74664402 ...,  0.11201498  0.55507243  0.        ]]

      [[ 0.05677766  0.          0.         ...,  0.          0.82949859  0.        ]
       [ 0.          0.          0.19032657 ...,  0.12606588  0.02242988  0.        ]
       [ 0.10961182  0.          1.54800272 ...,  0.37970039  0.          0.        ]
       [ 0.42456442  0.          1.87542152 ...,  0.36944041  0.29935738  0.        ]]

      [[ 0.04067653  0.          0.         ...,  0.          0.55476826  0.        ]
       [ 0.31820443  0.          0.         ...,  0.          0.          0.        ]
       [ 0.58587539  0.          0.25692856 ...,  0.03251171  0.          0.        ]
       [ 0.66836131  0.          0.19993514 ...,  0.          0.19460687  0.        ]]

      [[ 0.46838504  0.          0.         ...,  0.          0.91270626  0.        ]
       [ 1.46697009  0.          0.         ...,  0.          0.53989708  0.        ]
       [ 2.26325178  0.          0.         ...,  0.          0.          0.        ]
       [ 1.71381867  0.          0.         ...,  0.          0.34278265  0.        ]]]]
```

Comment: bottleneck_features_train is of type numpy.ndarray, it's not a simple byte array/string. You can't simply write it to a file. What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Use numpy's dedicated [routines](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.io.html). (better than string and general-pickle-based approaches mentioned here). You can even consider [joblib](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/persistence.html) (heavily used by sklearn).

Comment: @Omer i am using 2.7

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write your numpy array straight to file and be able to load it again, you should use `pickle`

To write it:

```
import pickle

with open("pickle_file.pickle", "wb") as handle:
    pickle.dump(your_array, handle)
```

To read it:

```
with open("pickle_file.pickle", "rb") as handle:
    your_array = pickle.load(handle)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to a string object.

**Ex:**

```
generator1 = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255).flow_from_directory(train_data_dir,target_size=(img_width, img_height),batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=False)
    print("generator1 images loaded")

    for i in range(len(generator1)):
        kl = generator1[i]
        bottleneck_features_train = model.predict_on_batch(kl[0])
        print("first prediction")
        print (bottleneck_features_train)
        file =open('/home/rehan/predictions/bottleneck_features_train_%s.py'%i, 'w')
        file.write(str(bottleneck_features_train))
        file.close()
```